# AngularJS - ng-repeat to display empty cell/s when data is not available when using slice twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple ng-repeat that loops through a JSON file with a list of countries and details about that country e.g. currency, population for a particular set of months (24 in this case)

My ng-repeat loops through the first 12 months successfully, and displaying the corresponding text when the ng-switch criteria is met.

Additionally, for the first 12 months, if there is no data available, then 'empty' is displayed in the cell.

However, as i am using 2 `ng-repeats` and `slice`, i cant seem to get my `getEmptyCells` function to work/display empty for months greater than 12.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-controller="EventController">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="country in Countries">
        <th>{{country.countryName}}</th>

        <td ng-repeat="countryDetails in country.Details.slice(0, 12)" ng-switch="countryDetails">
            <span ng-switch-when="11">Medium</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="22">Large</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="33">Larger</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="44">Very Large</span>
            <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.length)" class="empty">
            empty
        </td>            

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="country in Countries">
        <th>{{country.countryName}}</th>

        <td ng-repeat="countryDetails in country.Details.slice(13, 24)" ng-switch="countryDetails">
            <span ng-switch-when="11">Medium</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="22">Large</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="33">Larger</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="44">Very Large</span>
            <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.length)" class="empty">
            empty
        </td>            

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function EventController($scope) {
$scope.Countries = [
  {
      countryName:"USA",
      Details:[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,00,01,02,11,22]
  },
  {
      countryName:"UK",
      Details:[33,44,55,66]
  },
  {
      countryName:"Russia",
      Details:[77,88,99,00]
  }
];
$scope.getEmptyCells = function(len){
    var emptyCells = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
        emptyCells.push(i);
    }        
    return emptyCells;
}
}
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/2/  attempting to use 2 functions

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/3/  passing slice in getEmptyCells2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

First, you are not passing the right numbers to the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method for the months greater th an 12. The first parameter is the begin index.  For the first twelve months you used `country.Details.slice(0, 12)` which means start at index `0` and end at index `12` which is defined as

> Zero-based index at which to end extraction. slice extracts up to but not including end.

So you are using index 0-11 for the first 12 months (which adds up to 12 elements). In order to display the next twelve months, you need to start at index **12** not 13.

```
ng-repeat="countryDetails in country.Details.slice(12, 24)"
```

Now your second issue is that you aren't getting the right number of "empty" cells for your second table.  The reason is because you have not accounted for the fact that you are looking at the **next** 12 months, not the first 12.  The easiest way to fix this is to subtract 12 from the length parameter you use when you are displaying the next 12 months.

```
<td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.length-12)" class="empty">
        empty
</td>
```

**but** if you do this, make sure to update your `getEmptyCells` function to account for that and adjust if you get a negative number

```
$scope.getEmptyCells = function(len){
    var emptyCells = [];
    if (len<0) { len = 0; }
    for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
        emptyCells.push(i);
    }        
    return emptyCells;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/callado4/8hQ3R/5/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the above, it makes sense now. I have modified the ng-repeat emptyCell call to: <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.slice(0, 12).length)"></td>... then <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.slice(12, 24).length)"></td>..... <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.slice(24,36).length)"></td

Comment: What you wrote works, the only thing that I don't like too much about it is how you are doing a slice twice - once in the ng-repeat to show the "data" and once in the ng-repeat to show the empty cells.  If you create a directive that encapsulates your html structure creating logic then you could just pass the sliced array and not have to do a slice 2 times.